# Float a DIV centered over another DIV

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to float a div over another one but in the center (width).

EDIT: I want the container div to be over the top div and centered.

Current CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: auto;
}

#top {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

#container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 920px;
    height:300px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:auto;
}
```

This is what i get:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set left:50%
and margin-left:-460px (half the width of the div)

Comment: Thank You I had the same question!!!
Solved so! Idem for bottom:50% and margin too... +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's untested but you basically need to set the container div to relative and then the div inside that to absolute.

```
body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin: auto;
    }

#top {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

#container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 920px;
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
    right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting #top's position attribute to absolute and using a little javascript to set the left attribute to #container's left + half of #container's width - half of #top's width.

i.e, after including jQuery (untested):

`$(document).ready(function(){


    var topLeft = $("#container").css("left") + ($("#container").css("width")/2) - ($("#top").css("width")/2);


    $("#top").css("left", topLeft);


});`

In the case that left is zero, like the example you gave, that $("#container").css("left") term is unnecessary.

EDIT: You'll also have to be sure to set the z-index attributes of the two divs appropriately.